# How can query params be pushed and used for this page in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I found this codebase from the tutorial. I am trying to fetch data from paginated API.

The thing is that it looks like there is no usage of react-router here.

```
 const [hits, setHits] = useState([]);
     const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(1); #New
    const [isLoaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [currentPage, setcurrentPage] = useState(0); #New
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('startups'); 

    const URL = `https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}&page=${currentPage}`;

    const handleFetch = () => {
        fetch(URL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(body => {
                setData([...body.hits]);
                                setPageCount(body.nbPages); #New
                                setisLoaded(true); #New
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
    };

      #New
    const handlePageChange = (selectedObject) => {
        setcurrentPage(selectedObject.selected);
        handleFetch();
    };

return (
    <div>
         <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={handleFetch}>Get Data</button>

            {isLoaded ? (
                hits.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <NewsCard
                            url={item.url}
                            title={item.title}
                            author={item.author}
                            key={item.objectID}
                        />
                    );
                })
            ) : (
                <div></div>
            )}    
                       #New
            {isLoaded ? (
                <ReactPaginate
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    pageRange={2}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                    containerClassName={'container'}
                    previousLinkClassName={'page'}
                    breakClassName={'page'}
                    nextLinkClassName={'page'}
                    pageClassName={'page'}
                    disabledClassNae={'disabled'}
                    activeClassName={'active'}
                />
            ) : (
                <div>Nothing to display</div>
            )} 

    </div>
);
  
}
```

How can be currentPage and Query used in react router as query parameters so default currentPage will be 1 if there is no any query or currentPage param in the URL and also whenever you change the query or currentPage URL will also be updated with '?' query parameters like  `https://example.com?currentPage=9&query=startup`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **history** to push query params into url,

```
history.push(`/?currentPage=${currentPage}&query=${queryString}`)
```

checkout this [repository](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) to learn more about **history**

Comment: Shouldn't I push the route where I currently in react-router?

Comment: you can push query parameters from your current component, there shouldn't be any issue.